# C++ sort with 'tweaked' compare functor

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std

I have a class functor (too complex to implement as a lambda), but to strip the idea down, I want to ensure the functor satisfies the [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) predicate. The issue is, I want all values larger than `(1)` to yield ascending order, but to place all values of `(1)` at the 'end' - e.g., treated as 'larger' values.

e.g., `{2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, ..., 1, 1, 1}`

The function object is implemented as a struct to extract arguments from a (complicated) object reference it is constructed with, but the important part is the method in the function object. To simplify:

```
bool operator () (unsigned i, unsigned j)
{
    if (i == 1) return false; // (1 >= x)
    if (j == 1) return true;  // (x <= 1)

    return (i < j);
}
```

This appears to work as expected with `std::sort` and `std::stable_sort`. But, I'm still not convinced it correctly satisfies the criteria for `Compare`, in terms of strict weak ordering. Note that `x <= 1` in all cases - that is, for: `i, j >= 1`. Clearly, `(1, 1) => false`

Is my 'tweaked' functor correct, even as it places values of `(1)` at the end? That is `(1)` has been handled to be interpreted as greater than values `x > 1`? Or have I just been lucky with my `sort` implementations?

---

As I should have clarified, the value `(0)` does not occur. I originally had this in a comment for the (very clever) accepted answer but mistakenly deleted it.

Comment: Looks OK to me as written. Just read `1` as "infinity" to convince yourself.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - that's very useful advice, since I explicitly eliminate the `i = 1` and `j = 1` cases prior to the compare. It's more the formal definitions of the `Compare` predicate that I'm not 100% certain about.

Comment: Well, [here are the requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). I'm not sure how I can help you convinve yourself that your predicate satisfies them.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - yes. I've tried writing out some boolean tables in accordance with that link, which leaves me *mostly* certain. I guess I'm just asking for corner-cases I might have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define a bijective operation in which the comparison is total/weak order then you are fine. 
It turns our that for your type (`unsigned`) this is simply `-=2`/`+=2`

```
bool operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const{
   return (i-2) < (j-2); // usigned will wrap around 0 
}
```

Well, that also depends what you want to do with zero.

This relies in `1 - 2 == std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` so when you "compare" e.g. `1` with `x` you get `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max() < x - 2` which is `false`, even if `x` is also `1` (it will be true for `0` if there is such).

Comment: This is inspired - and I believe that the condition will still evaluate as `false` even if `x = 1`, as desired.

Comment: Note: this will put `0` before `1` (original post did not specify where `0` goes)

Comment: @M.M. yes, the OP said in a comment that "there is no zero". He later deleted the comment. That's why I wrote "that also depends what you want to do with zero."

Comment: @M.M - sorry about that, it was a mistake deleting the comment, but @alfC is correct about my previous statement of no `(0)` values.